# C#: Remove function isn't removing the exact index

Tags: c#

Can someone please check why it isn't removing exact character (`ind`) from the string?

When I execute below, the char `'<'` at position 17 is not removed, I see it's removing `'2'`, also I tried with `ind - 2` to remove `'<'` but it doesn't work for the next special character.

Please note that I need to use the below code to remove special chars.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = "<X><A>this is AA<123 w<o<r<d</A></X>";
        int xx = 0;
        bool bFlg = true;
        XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
        while (bFlg)
        {
            try
            {
                xx++;
                x.LoadXml(path);
                bFlg = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
//"Name cannot begin with the '1' character, hexadecimal value 0x31. Line 1, position 18."
                string toBeSearched = "position";
                int ix = ee.Message.IndexOf(toBeSearched);

                if (ix != -1)
                {
                    var pos = ee.Message.Substring(ix + toBeSearched.Length);
                    pos = Regex.Replace(pos, @"[^\d]", "");
                    path = path.Remove(Convert.ToInt32(pos), 1);
                    bFlg = true;
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception(ee.Message);
                if (xx > 20)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This won't even compile, you've used `x` twice, I think `int x = 0` should be `int il = 0 `

Comment: `"<X><A>this is AA<123 w<o<r<d</A></X>"` us pradon my silly question, is this xml or an html you are dealing with? are you trying to create an xml cleanser?

Comment: I just editted.

Comment: @BagusTesa - that`s xml.

Comment: That's not XML because you have un-encoded `<` in the data. What are you attempting to do ehre?

Comment: That`s my xml string and am trying to remove only those chars which doesnt allow me to load xml to 'x'

Comment: Don't use backticks (`\``) where you should use apostophes (`'`) in your english text, as backticks are used to delimit code.

Comment: Regex.Replace(path, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);

Comment: what does this do? please explain.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - somehow those backticks fit well with the question.

Comment: @Matt I can`t use that, it`ll remove all the '<' & '>' and I won`t be able to load string to 'x'(XmlDocument)

Comment: You should include the exception message in the question. Saves a lot of time. Because I don't see why the char at 17 (`<123` ) would produce the error.

Comment: And the error message would use a 1-based numbering, off-by-1.

Comment: When deleting items from a list you always have to start at the end and work towards the beginning. If you have 3,4,5 and remove 3.  The index of each item becomes one less and you end up skipping 4.

Comment: @jdweng why can't it take the position passed as index and remove it? even for the first time too it isn't working, how can I start from the end?

Comment: This seems a desperate attempt to fix a XML which can't be fixed. Where does this XML come from and why is it misshaped?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Why can`t the xml be fixed? we`re getting such chars in xml and need to handle them.

Comment: Or, put correctly -- someone is handing you a document which is not written in XML, and you are trying to translate it into a document which is written in XML. A device which translates from one language to another is called a *compiler*, and I suggest that you actually write one rather than hacking this up.  Write a specification for the language you intend to recognize, parse that language, and then define rules for translating from your language to XML.

Comment: They could also be trying to fix an irreversible mistake they made, pretty quick fix anyway

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit messy.. but given your current test case, it works.

```
string path = "<X><A>this is AA<123 w<o<r<d</A></X>";
int pathLength = path.Length;
List<int> positons = new List<int>();
for (int itr = 0; itr < pathLength; itr++) {
    if (path[itr] == '<') {
        for (int pointer = itr + 1; pointer < pathLength; pointer++) {
            if (path[pointer] == '<') {
                positons.Add(itr);
                break;
            } else if (path[pointer] == '>') {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
int offset = 0;
foreach(var pos in positons) {
    path = path.Remove(pos - offset, 1);
    offset++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the path is always enclosed within the same tags (since this was not specified, I'm not sure), it can be as simple as removing the leading and trailing tags:

```
const string LeadingTags = "<X><A>";
const string TrailingTags = "</A></X>";

string path = "<X><A>this is AA<123 w<o<r<d</A></X>";
int length = path.Length - LeadingTags.Length - TrailingTags.Length;
string value = path.Substring(LeadingTags.Length, length);
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Prints the correct value:

> this is AA<123 w<o<r<d